# Add ID attribute to last row only in jQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to get the last row in `DataTable` as I need to add a style to this row only *not* the last row of every page, so no CSS. I have the following code which identifies the last row in the `DataTable`

```
"initComplete": function () {
     var last_row = existingRuleTable.row(':last').data();
     console.log(last_row);
}
```

This returns the following:

[image]

Which when looking at the `DataTable` is correct:

[image]

But I can't add CSS to *this* row only.

I have tried some of the below

```
last_row.attr('id', 'ABC');
last_row.row('tr:last').attr('id', 'ABC');
last_row.css('color', 'red');
```

But always get an error similar to

> last_row.row is not a function

Comment: You're asking that same question for the third time already. Can you explain, why solution, provided by me in your previous question didn't work? To remind, it boils down to 
`() => {
    const table = $('#mytable').DataTable();
    $(table.row(table.rows(':last')).node()).find('button').remove();
  }`

Comment: ...but, of course, this time, instead of find and remove the button you need to use `.addClass()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following seemed to help me

```
"initComplete": function () {
     $(this.api().cell(':last', 7, {order:'original'}).node()).css('display', 'none');
},
```

7 is the column number

Comment: Have you even noticed that the code, that allegedly solved your problem **does not** add an id attribute to the last row (as your question header reads), it sets CSS style property 'display' to 'none' for one particular **cell** in the last row? Haven't you messed things up entirely?

Comment: @ygorbunkov Yeh i did but then realised after i tried the code i didn't need to add an attribute, it was a style but i'd already added the answer so left it alone